# Can kindle be a synonym of amazon?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have two overlapping tags:

[kindle](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kindle) (33 questions)

> This tag should be used for questions related to publishing on
>   Amazon's Kindle, a tool to read E-Books.
>
> This tag should be used for questions related to publishing on
>   amazon's Kindle, a tool to read ebooks. You should mention what kind
>   of writing you are working on, such as whether you are talking about a
>   fantasy novel, and you should mention what your specific problem ist,
>   such as the process of self-publishing or the marketing and sales.

[amazon](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon) (23 questions)

> This tag should be used for questions about the writing related
>   services that the company Amazon provides, such as questions about
>   payment when publishing on Kindle.
>
> This tag should be used for questions about the writing related
>   services that the company Amazon provides, such as questions about
>   payment when publishing on kindle.

[7 questions currently use both tags](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon+kindle).

While I can see that the tags are different (Kindle is a subset of Amazon and the Amazon tag is more about services, not the logistics of publishing), they overlap a lot and neither is so popular it needs to be divided.

Also, Amazon has multiple publishing services (such as Comixology and CreateSpace) and we don't want separate tags for all of them, right?

I can't officially propose a synonym as I don't have enough points in either tag.  So I'm asking here:

### Can we merge these and make [kindle](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kindle) a synonym of [amazon](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon) (and then change the wiki to reflect the change and add in other Amazon publishing imprints)?

Comment: What would be the benefit of doing this? While there is overlap there is enough distinction for when to use one tag or both. Yes [tag:kindle] is a subset of [tag:amazon] but as it is the more popular tag I gather than it is more popular than all their other services combined. Additionally I can see the amazon tag being used for a variety of thing that don't relate to kindle and it's inappropriate for kindle to redirect to. e.g. Advertising or self-publishing paperbacks on amazon.

Comment: @linksassin I am really not seeing how or why there needs to be two separate tags.  Kindle books are e-books sold on Amazon for use on Amazon devices or on computers/phones with Amazon software.  Are there really many questions that are very specific to the Kindle platform only?

Comment: I don't know, but based on the usage of the tag I'd assume there is. Tags are meant to reflect usage. I just don't see what harm having both is doing, if people use them correct what benefit does removing or synonymising have?

Comment: I think the [tag:amazon] tag should definitely be updated to include all of their other services as well. But we don't need to synonymise kindle with it.

Comment: @linksassin What about [tag:kindle] do we need that isn't covered by [tag:amazon] and [tag:ebook]?

Comment: I don't know. But I don't need to know. That's not what tags are for. 33 users have found it useful. We shouldn't mess with things unless there is a clear benefit. There is a reason it takes a minimum rep to suggest a synonym.

Comment: Also reading through the questions there is a case for [tag:kindle] to be a synonym of [tag:ebook] instead. I think it has a specific enough use case to exist.

Comment: @linksassin LOL weren't there dozens (over 100?) questions that used the tag [tag:story] you just got rid of?  With my full support.  And all the other reorg that went on with the plot and narrative related tags.  The fact that 33 users thought of Kindle first when tagging and 23 thought first of Amazon and others thought ebook (with of course them not all overlapping) doesn't mean there isn't duplication going on.  That's what I'm trying to suss out.

Comment: To put it another way... I can think of plenty of [tag:amazon] questions that are not related to [tag:kindle] but no [tag:kindle] questions that are not also [tag:amazon].  Likewise, there are plenty of [tag:ebook] questions that have nothing to do with  [tag:kindle] but no [tag:kindle] questions that are not also [tag:ebook]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93080/discussion-between-linksassin-and-cyn).

Answer (score 2):

## No, there is a use case for both

I don't see a significant benefit in synonymizing these tags. Yes, [kindle](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kindle) is *mostly* a subset of [amazon](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon) but not entirely. I can see cases where people want to specifically ask about kindle and not the rest of the amazon services.

#### The amazon tag wiki needs to be expanded

Amazon has a lot of writing and technical services that are not related to kindle. This tag should reflect that and not just be restricted to kindle topics. It needs to be updated and expanded with more examples and use cases.

Some examples where is has been used for non-kindle related topics:

- [How many blank lines before scene headings (and secondary scene headings) using Amazon Storywriter](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/44430/how-many-blank-lines-before-scene-headings-and-secondary-scene-headings-using)
- [How many pixels' margin to the right should my 5"-wide image be on a 300dpi KDP paperback to be centered?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/40337/how-many-pixels-margin-to-the-right-should-my-5-wide-image-be-on-a-300dpi-kdp)
- [What, if anything, can I do about Amazon reviews being one-sidedly censored?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/28409/what-if-anything-can-i-do-about-amazon-reviews-being-one-sidedly-censored)
- [How to view all book reviews in one place?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/18259/how-to-view-all-book-reviews-in-one-place)
- [How important is a BISAC Category?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/14186/how-important-is-a-bisac-category)
- [If I get a free ISBN through Amazon's CreateSpace now, will that impact any decisions about getting my own ISBN later?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/12952/if-i-get-a-free-isbn-through-amazons-createspace-now-will-that-impact-any-deci)

If I want to learn/ask about kindle specifically I shouldn't have to sort through all of these questions to find the relevant ones on my tag. The kindle tag is not a synonym for these questions and shouldn't be a synonym of amazon.

#### Not all kindle questions are amazon questions

There are [26 questions tagged kindle but not amazon](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kindle+-amazon). The argument that these could all be tagged as amazon isn't hard to make though and in most cases is probably correct. I question the benefit of this though. Replacing [kindle](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kindle) with [amazon](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon) on these questions only makes the tagging less specific and broader.

## Don't fix what ain't broke

Both tags existing causes no harm to the site. Unlike [our recent discussion on plot tags](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1980/33442), [kindle](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kindle) and [amazon](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon) are fairly well used. The reason to synonymize the plot tags was to make questions easier to find, previously questions were split over 3 tags of near identical meaning, we fixed that. I this case most questions either use both tags or use the more precise tag for their use case. For plot is was unclear of the hierachy, here it is obvious that [amazon](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon) is a superset of [kindle](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kindle). Therefore it's easier to tell which tag should be used and we don't need to remove one.